# How to hide value labels when zooming out in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I'm using `Swift` version of `MPAndroidChart` and trying to figure out how to hide value labels when a few of them are located too close together and start to overlap on a line chart.

Hiding all the value labels when zoomed out to a certain point works too(still don't know how to do it), but hiding only the ones that are overlapping would be the best.

I know that I can manually call `setDrawValues = false`, but I want it to be called automatically on zoom.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RybV2.jpg)

Comment: there should be a didZoom delegate. so you need to set setDrawValues=false in that delegate after check zoom factor to hide it.

Comment: Thanks @GeneCode, but I can't find didZoom delegate. Could you point me to docs/source code where it's defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, I use the same as iOS

1: Find the difference between 1st and 2nd index  y-axis label(YAxisRenderer)

```
     for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
     {

        String text = mYAxis.getFormattedLabel(i);

        double value1=Double.parseDouble(mYAxis.getFormattedLabel(1).replace(",",""));

        double value2=Double.parseDouble(mYAxis.getFormattedLabel(2).replace(",",""));


        result=(value2-value1)-40;
        //POPreferences.setDifference(String.valueOf(result));


        c.drawText(text, fixedPosition, positions[i * 2 + 1] + offset, mAxisLabelPaint);
    }
```

2: Use result variable when text draws on bar or line(BarChartRenderer.java):

```
  if (result >= vals[k / 2])
    {

    drawValue(c,dataSet.getValueFormatter(),vals[k / 2], entry, i, x, y,color);                                                                                          

      }
```

Comment: This question is in Swift, but this answer is in Java. Can you post a Swift version?

Comment: Hello Michael ,
  you can apply the same logic  on IOS MpChart Library  Class